# no me guarda toma la url de la imagen para guardar

Tags: flutter

Buenas tardes ando desarrollando en flutter y se me presenta el siguiente percance
la imagen me la sube a firestore  pero la url de la imagen par guardar en la BD no la obtiene

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es en consola

y en database mira que no se añade la ruta
pero donde debería de ir la url es null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que muestra en ese print the URL IMAGE

Comment: al imprimir me muestra la ruta de la imagen en el storage

Comment: Entonces cual es el problema? esa imagen se la pasas a updateTiendaData,, llega ahí o no ? donde se queda?

Comment: mira adjunto pantallas no se porque si obtiene todas menos la ruta

Comment: pues entonces el error está en `updateTiendaData` , me pregunto porque no verificaste ese método si la URL llegaba bien del storage, pero no actualizaba Firestore :/

Comment: como asi ? por que la URL que obtengo del storage la ingreso en el navegador y me direcciona a la imagen, lo que me parece extraño es que solo con la imagen sabiendo que esta esta buena

Comment: una cosa es el storage y otra firestore,  la imagen la crea y la obtienes bien, pero se nota que no está actaulizando firestore con la URL de la imagen, por eso revisa tu método `updateTiendaData` para ver que hace y si llega la imagen ahí para que actualice firestore

Comment: vale muchas gracias voy a mirar el metodo updateTiendaData